# Получить количество дней в месяце

Tags: javascript

```js
//идея от участника Igor 
 
  var date1 = new Date(2019, 5, 1);
  var date2 = new Date(2019, 6, 1);
  var date3 = date2 - date1
  console.log(date3);
  
  var date1 = new Date(2019, 5, 1);
  var date2 = new Date(2019, 6, 1);
  var s = date1.getDay();
  var s1 = date2.getDay();
  var s3 = s1 - s
  console.log(s3);
```

Пытаюсь сделать собственный календарь натолкнулся на такую проблему как получить кол-во дней в месяце

```js
var date = new Date;

var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
var day = month.getDay();
console.log(month);
console.log(day);
```

Пришла только такая идея, но получаю ошибку как можно решить иначе ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener('input', function () {
  var m = +document.getElementById('m').value
  var y = +document.getElementById('y').value
  
  var days = new Date(y, m, 0).getDate()
  document.querySelector('output').textContent = days + " in " + m + "." + y
})
```

```css
input { vertical-align: middle; }
```

```html
<input type=range id=m min=1 max=12 value=5>
<input type=number id=y min=100 max=9999 value=2019>
<output>31 in 5.2019</output>
```

Comment: var m = +document.getElementById('m').value  этой строкой кода мы получает id получаем значение value и приводим его к числу ?

Comment: _"кода мы получает id"_ - муть какая-то, остальное - да.

Comment: значение id так верно ?

Comment: вряд ли. получаем элемент по id, достаём из него значение и приводим к числу.

Comment: такое объяснение лучше  :))

Comment: вставим обработчик событий addEventListener на document; document - это что ? страница html документа ?

Comment: а может сам поищешь? к тому же, это вообще к твоему вопросу не относится

Comment: простите :(( пойду искать

Comment: поискал как я его понял document - объект страницы создается когда html страница загружается в браузер

Answer (score 1):

Создать дату первого числа нужного месяца и дату первого числа следующего месяца, и найти разницу в днях между ними.

```js
var date1 = new Date(2019, 1, 1);
var date2 = new Date(2019, 2, 1);
var date3 = Math.round((date2 - date1) / 1000 / 3600 / 24);
console.log(date3);
```

Comment: здравствуйте посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Муть какая-то...

Comment: @Qwertiy Здравствуйте надеюсь не меня ругаете :(( P.S. завтра буду Ваш код разбирать :)

Comment: @Igor спасибо завтра буду Ваш код разбирать :)

Comment: @Igor Здравствуйте скажите откуда Вы взяли числа 1000, 3600, 24

Comment: @Leks 1000 миллисекунд в секунде, 3600 секунд в часе, 24 часа в дне

Comment: @Igor понятно теперь спасибо, пойду теперь Qwertiy доставать :))

Answer (score 0):

*Элегантный способ получение даты:*

```js
Date.prototype.daysInMonth = function() {
  return 33 - new Date(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth(), 33).getDate();
};

alert(new Date().daysInMonth());
```